# Windows recovery backup error - Sony Vaio Recovery Center

Tags: windows, sony-vaio

When I'm trying to create a recovery backup, I get the following error:

> `The disc could not be created.:boot.iso missing, oscdimg.exe failed.`

And recovery process halts. I am using Window Vista Business and a Sony Vaio laptop.

EDIT:

I am using Sony Vaio's recovery center. Then I after I tried to create disk. My laptop has also a recovery drive which appears only when I click on Vaio's recovery center.

Comment: please add more tags and tell us which software you are using and more general details.

Comment: did you mean Sony VAIO?

Comment: yes, it is Sony VAIO.

Comment: oscdimg.exe is part of Windows library. You might have reomved/uninstalled something that relies on this exe. You could try and reisntall VAIO recovery, its possible it might isntall all the dependencies again.

Comment: try using [Windows Backup and Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore) instead.